# Unexpected frame of subview (Swift)

Tags: swift

My code displays my view `initialview` as a subview of the container `containerView`.

I'm expecting `initialView.frame` to be the frame in the coordinates of the superview (that is the containerview) - which is reported int he playground to be (0,0,0,0) - but it is then displayed in the container so how can the width and height possibly be zero, as reported?

[image]

The playground code -

```
final class InitialView: UIView {
    let traverseButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    let networkButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    let networkLabel = UILabel()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.backgroundColor = .red
        traverseButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
        traverseButton.setTitle("Go to Detail", for: .normal)
        traverseButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        traverseButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.addSubview(traverseButton)
        traverseButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        traverseButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        traverseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        networkButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
        networkButton.setTitle("Make Network Call", for: .normal)
        networkButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        networkButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.addSubview(networkButton)
        networkButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        networkButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        networkButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true

        networkLabel.text = "No network calls made"
        networkLabel.backgroundColor = .purple
        self.addSubview(networkLabel)

        networkLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        networkLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        networkLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true
        networkLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        networkLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }

    func setNetworkLabel(text: String){
        networkLabel.text = text
    }
}

var initialView: InitialView?
initialView = InitialView()

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 500, height: 1000))
containerView.addSubview(initialView!)

initialView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

initialView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
initialView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
initialView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
initialView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably put the `initialView?.frame` line *before* the `containerView` line.

Although you have added the constraints, before Xcode playgrounds actually *renders* the `containerView`, its subviews are not laid out. That's why `initialView`'s frame remains at its default value of `(0, 0, 0, 0)`. If you actually manually tell `containerView` that it should lay out its subviews, `initialView`'s frame will be set correctly.

There are many ways to do this:

- move the line where you inspect `initialView?.frame` after the line where you inspect `containerView`
- call `containerView.setNeedsLayout()` first
- call `containerView.layoutIfNeeded()` first